# Is it possible to pass parameters to servlet/jsp using a href link?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Is it possible to pass parameters to servlet/jsp  using a href link?
If so can anybody give an example to show how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course:

```
<a href="link.do?user=31"/>
```

Read it in your servlet handling `link.do` URI:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  req.getParameter("user")  //equals "31"
}
```

Or if it's a servlet (`link.jsp`):

```
<%= request.getParameter("user") %>
```

...or better with [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl):

```
${param.age}
```

Comment: I dont get it... like I have a variable user and I want to link it to a3.jsp... now should i mention it in d href tag? how exactly?

Comment: @user1607653: where do you have this variable? In JavaScript? In Java and you are generating the HTML including this `href`? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have this code in my servlet page. The variable name is "user". now using href i want to link it to a3.jsp and also pass the variable user.

Comment: ok cool... Thanks a lot... One last doubt, what if I have more than one  variable

Comment: @user1607653 `link.do?user=31&name=Tom` - the second variable is `"name"`